# Codeigniter 4 while unlinking shows the error: Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Into my project in Codeigniter 4 I want to delete the record from database as well as I want to unlink the file present into that record but it gives me the error of

```
Trying to access array offset on value of type null
```

Till now I have tried this but its not working according to what do I want, below is my code

```
public function delete($id = null)
{

    $model = new AbcModel();
    

    try{
        $id=$this->request->getPost('id');
        $this->record = $model->where('id', $id)->first();
        $image = $this->record['image'];

        if(unlink('.'.$image)){
            $model->where('id', $id)->delete();
            echo "delete";

        }
        

        
    }
    catch(\Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
}
```

My Model

```
<?php namespace App\Models;
 
class AbcModel extends MyModel
{

protected $table = 'abc';
protected $primaryKey = 'id';

}
```

Into the database I have saved the file as `/public/uploads/abcfolder/Tulips.jpg`

Comment: without seeing your AbcModel, one can only guess the reason for what is described in the error message *Trying to access array offset on value of type null*

Comment: @Vickel Okay I am Updating my model

Comment: I'm sorry, what line is throwing the error?

Comment: @Vickel As i Said Above no line is shown Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have problem with your delete query not with unlinking so you are getting the error of `Trying to access array offset on value of type null`. So I have rectified your codes try it once

```
$id=$this->request->getPost('id');
$model = new CurriculumModel();
$record = $model->find($id);
$image = $record['image'];

$file='.'.$image;
if(is_file($file))
{
    unlink($file);
    $model->delete($id);
    echo 'delete';
}
```

This code does works for me, I am not sure whether it will work for you or not but give it a try.

Comment: Hey @Rstdevepzz Thanks it worked for me... Yes you were right i was wrong with delete query.

Answer (score 0):

so it like me

```
<?php namespace Modules\Common\Libraries;

use CodeIgniter\HTTP\Response;

class  CustomFile
{
    protected string $error;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->error = '';
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getError(): string
    {
        return $this->error;
    }

    public function removeSingleFile( $path)
    {
        try {

            if (file_exists($path)) {
                unlink($path);
            }


        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();

        }

    }


    


}
```

in your ctl or service

```
/**
     * edit function
     * @method : DELETE with params ID
     * @param $id
     * @param $foreignKey
     */
    public function delete($id)
    {


$cfs  = new  CustomFile();
$model = new MyModel();

            $deleteById = $model->where(['id' => $id])->findAll();
          
        

        if (is_null($deleteById)) $this->httpException(lang('Shared.api.exist'), ResponseInterface::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);


        $model->where(['id' => $id])->delete();

        foreach ($deleteById as $path) {

            $cfs->removeSingleFile(ROOTPATH . $path->path);
        }


    }
```